# Why isn't my program recognizing my target object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class AIController : MonoBehaviour {

[Header("Player interaction")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject target;
[SerializeField] private int damage;
[SerializeField] private float attackDelay;
[SerializeField] private float stunTime;
[SerializeField] private int health;

public int Health{
    get{return health; }
    set{ health = value;
        agent.speed = runningSpeed;
        agent.SetDestination(target.transform.position);
        onPatrol = false;
        if (health <= 0){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
        CanAttack(target);
}
```

here i want to make sure that the AI will attack the player only when he is in front of the AI and within .5 meters. the reason i use this instead of OnTriggerEnter is that the AI will only end up attacking once and then just stand on top of the player without really doing anything further

```
void CanAttack (GameObject other)
{
    Vector3 vectorToTarget = other.transform.position - transform.position;
    float angleToTarget = Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, vectorToTarget);

    if (angleToTarget <= FOV)
    {
        RaycastHit raycastData;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, vectorToTarget, out raycastData, .5f))
        {
            GameObject newTarget = raycastData.collider.gameObject;
            Attack(target);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also used Attack(other) and this still does not work

```
void Attack(GameObject other)
{
    if (!hasAttacked)//if the AI has not recently attacked
    {
        if (!Player.isShieldOn)//if the player shield is not up
        {
            if (!Player.hasShieldBraclet)//if the player has the shield braclet
            {
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().Health -= damage - ShieldBraclet.dmgReduction;//reduce the amount of damage taken
            }
            else
            {
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().Health -= damage;//otherwise take normal damage
            }
            StartCoroutine("DelayAttack");//delay time until AI can attack again
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(Stun(stunTime));//if the shield was up stun this enemy
        }
    }
}
```

this is used to make sure that the AI waits a moment before attacking again that way the player doesn't die instantly upon touching the AI.

```
IEnumerator DelayAttack()
{
    hasAttacked = true;//the AI has attacked
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackDelay);//wait to attack again
    hasAttacked = false;//the AI can now attack again
}
```

}

For the most part everything runs fine but when it reaches the code to deal damage to the player it tells me that the object reference is not set to an instance of an object. How can I fix this?

The Specific error code is: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Enemy.Attack(UnityEngine.GameObject other).
This is referring to the line

```
other.gameObject.GetComponent<Player>().Health -= damage - ShieldBraclet.dmgReduction;//reduce the amount of damage taken
```

Comment: PS: though it might be obvious i thought it might be important to note that yes i have also tried using Attack(newTarget) as well as Attack(raycastData.collider) with the parmeter needing a collider

Comment: Did you dragged the target gameobject to the inspector? select the gameobject this script is attached, and drag and drop the target game object to its field in the inspector.

Comment: Yes, i have made sure to do that.

Comment: Please add the full Unity error and indicate what line of code in your samples above that error corresponds to.  There are 3 objects in `Attack` and it's not contextually clear which is giving you trouble.

Comment: hopefully that edit helps to clarify what the issue is.

Comment: Make sure `target` contains a Player componnent

Comment: What @itay_421 said and also double check that `ShieldBraclet` is a valid object.  You might also try dumping `other.name` to the log and verify that `other` is the object you think it is.